# Testing callback function with big arrow function

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, callback, arrow-functions

I've got a function that is a callback and receives another callback .

```
const filterDays = (daysLimit, cb)=> {
   return (err, items) => {
      if(err) return cb(err);
      return cb(undefined, items.filter(item => item.daysOld < daysLimit));
   };
};
```

The function is working but I want to do some unit testing and I wonder how to pass directly some predefined data to test it. Something like...?

Comment: Looks like you've figured it out?

Answer (score 0):

After some testing I found out a small error in the definition... that's why the simple:

const res = filterDays(daysLimit, (err, item) => {return item;})(null, data);

didn't work at the beginning...